# Caliburn Micro, Notify when property in nedsted object is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-structures, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I'm developing a C# WPF application for data management. I'm using the MVVM pattern with the Caliburn Micro framework.
I have a button that should only be pressable when a certain textbox with the name is not empty.

---

My problem is that when I enter text in the textbox the `CanSaveSelection` does not get notified and so doesn't check if it's empty.

```cs
public class MainWorkspaceViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Car _myCar;
    public Car MyCar
    {
        get { return _myCar; }
        set
        {
            _myCar = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSaveSelection);
        }
    }

    public void SaveSelection()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public bool CanSaveSelection
    {
        get
        {
            bool result = true;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyCar.Manufacturer.Name))
            {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The Objects:

```cs
public class Car : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to "bubble" up NotifyOfPropertyChange thought the objects?
I think another way of doing this is with the Event Aggregator but I don't really know much about that.

Comment: Where is the source property that the "certain textbox" is bound to defined?

Comment: @mm8 the property that the textbox is bound to is the Name property from the class Manufacurer. So in this case the binding path would be:                                     
Path = MyCar.Manufacturer.Name

Comment: Does the `Manufacturer` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @mm8 I saw that i forgot something in my question, I edited it in. Yes they do indirectly thought the PropertyChangedBase  base class.

Comment: If you can live with the button still being enabled, you could remove the canSave. In Save, just check there's a Name and return out of the method f there's none. Or you could bind a command which will re-evauluate canexecute on user input. Maybe Caliburn Micro isn't an ideal match for your project's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could the handle the `Manufacturer`'s `PropertyChanged` event it in your view model:

```
private Car _myCar;
public Car MyCar
{
    get { return _myCar; }
    set
    {
        if (_myCar != null && _myCar.Manufacturer != null)
            _myCar.Manufacturer.PropertyChanged -= OnManufacturerPropertyChanged;
        _myCar = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSaveSelection);
        if (_myCar != null && _myCar.Manufacturer != null)
            _myCar.Manufacturer.PropertyChanged += OnManufacturerPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OnManufacturerPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanSaveSelection));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but wouldn't that be an enormous amount of code when i had multiple properties with subproperties in Car ? Let say i have 10 more textboxes and every one of them is bound to a property inside a different property of Car. Wouldn't I need this code then times then ?

Comment: You will obviously need to subscribe to each object that raises `PropertyChanged` events. How else are you supposed to be notified?

Comment: Is there a way that all PropertyChanged events from the needed properties are catched in one "OnNeededPropertyChanged()" method ?

Comment: You can use the same event handler for all objects if that's what you mean.